# How do I resolve an error installing symfit - `Cannot uninstall sympy`

Tags: python, installation, symfit

I installed Anaconda3 and need to install symfit. Using `pip install symfit`, the program returns the error: `Cannot uninstall sympy`. It is a `distutils...."` It seems symfit requires `sympy 1.1.1`, but my Anaconda installation already installed `sympy 1.3` and the `symfit installer` objects to that. How can I get around this incompatibility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to create a new conda environment and try out the installations in that environment to avoid the conflict between different package versions. Tried the same in Centos and it is working fine.
Try out the following steps:

1) Create a conda environment:

```
conda create -n my_env python=3
```

2) Activate the environment:

```
source activate my_env
```

3) Install the symfit package

```
pip install symfit
```

Please note that 'my_env' is the environment name. Hope this solves your issue.

Regards,

Dona

Comment: Hi Dona, Wow. Thanks for that. It installed symfit without an error including the expected 1.1.1 version of sympy. Thanks a bunch. From the <my_env> anaconda prompt, I typed 'spyder' which opened OK. But when I import sympy and enter print (sympy.__version__), it returns '1.3', which causes an error in my call to symfit. My program was running fine with the older version 1.1.1 of sympy. How can I get it to import the older version of sympy now that it's installed in this environment? Thanks again, Y.

Comment: Try installing spyder in your activated environment(my_env) using conda install. The command is "conda install -c anaconda spyder" .  Then start spyder by typing "spyder" in the chosen environment(my_env) and check the version of sympy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, installing spyder and symfit within the virtual environment worked perfectly and my original problem installing symfit and running my program are solved. A few other commands from the Anaconda prompt I learned working with virtual environments are "where spyder", which locates the various instances that have been installed and "conda info --envs", which lists the virtual environments that have been created. Thanks again.